# Why is “נא” in parenthesis in birkas hamazon?

Tags: bentching, nusach-ashkenaz

I bentch using a regular Ashkenaz bentcher. In most of them, the word after “Rachem” is Na but it’s in parenthesis. I think I’ve also seen the word omitted occasionally.

I see the Shulchan Aruch 188:4 brings the Nusach as Rachem, without any Yesh Omrim, nor does the Rema comment. Where are sources that say to add the word Na?

Comment: To your title, usually parentheses in siddurim mean the word is omitted by some.

Comment: The Kabbalists believe it has special sanctity and therefore shtipped it in (as per the ArtScroll book on Birkat Hamazon)